# Where is the charging animation file on a SGS3 mini

Tags: android

I've been searching a bit around and couldn't find the file that holds the animation of the **Samsung Galaxy S3 mini**.
I am referring to the one that appears on the screen when the phone is turned off and charging.
THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my experience with this try the following files:

```
/system/bin/lpmkey
```

Or the like.